# All cookies are no sending for subdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, cookies

I'm trying to make an API call from one domain to another subdomain, I'm using jquery ajax for that, My problem is some cookies are sending while some are not sending. I want all the cookies to send.
If I'm consoling document.cookie before sending the request in

```
                    var cookie = document.cookie;
                    console.info( "adding cookie:                        "+ cookie );          
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Cookie', cookie);
                  },
```

It is printing all the cookies but some how in a request all the cookies are not sending.

```
        try {
            window.$.ajax({
                url: requestUrl,
                method: 'GET',
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'callbackFnc',
                // headers: { 'Cookie': document.cookie },
                crossDomain: true,
                 // beforeSend : function(xhr) {  
                //     var cookie = document.cookie;
                //     console.info( "adding cookie:                        "+ cookie );          
                //     xhr.setRequestHeader('Cookie', cookie);
                //   },
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },

                timeout: 5000,
                error: (xhr) => {
                    if (xhr && xhr.status === 200) {
                        resolve(true);
                    } else {
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                },
                success: (data, status, xhr) => {
                    if (xhr && xhr.status === 200) {
                        resolve(true);
                    } else {
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            resolve(false);
        }
```

Request header : -

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: abc=xy;
```

Comment: Are you making a cross-domain request? Are the cookies restricted to your current domain?

Comment: I'm making request from example.com to abc.example.com

Comment: How are you setting the cookies? Have you explicitly set the domain on them? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/519413

Comment: No I haven't set the domain but for one subdomain it is sending but for other it is not sending.